# Connected App setting changes in manage package after installation, how we keep it same?

Tags: community, managed-package, connected-apps, package, isv

we have a connected app that has ‘Relaxed IP restrictions’ in this development org. It is part of the managed package. When I install it in another org, the connected app comes as ‘Enforced IP restrictions’. Is that expected? How can we keep it relaxed?